# Steady-state VS equilibrium path

Tags: solow

In solow model, you can find steady-state of transformed variable $\hat{y}^{*} =\left(\frac{s}{n+g+\delta+n g}\right)^{\frac{a}{1-a}}$. If $s$ goes up, $\hat{y^*}$ goes up, and we can say a higher $s$ is better by just comparing old and new steady-states. Maybe, because $s$ does not affect the balanced growth path of the steady-state, comparing $\hat{y^*}$ for different values of $s$ is enough even though what we care about is non-transformed variables.

However, the same cannot be said for an increase in $g$, right? Thus, we need to compare the entire equilibrium path of the steady-state of the non-transformed variables. For example, $y_{t}^{*}=A_{0}(1+g)^{t}\left(\frac{s}{n+g+\delta+n g}\right)^{\frac{a}{1-a}}$ because $g$ affects the entire balanced growth path, and not just $\hat{y^*}$.

But the problem is the choice of $t$ affects whether $y_{t}^{*}$ under a higher $g$ is better or worse. For example, for $t<n$, $y_{t}^{*}$ under a higher $g$ is worse. And for $t>n+i, \; i = (0,1,2,3...)$, $y_{t}^{*}$ under a higher $g$ is better.

So I guess a higher $g$ is better for an economy in the long-run $t>n+i, \; i = (0,1,2,3...)$. If we wanna compare $y_{t}^{*}$ under old and new $g$, what $t$ to choose?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "*better*"? In terms of consumption, or utility? Or just raw output, though most people would argue that $s = 100\%$ is a bad way to live?

Comment: Also, if you really want to have a normative "*better*" as in one path is better than the other then why are you assuming the economy is always on the equilibrium path instead of just approaching it from a specific capital level? An analogy is examining if a KIA or a Ferrari would be a better car to have, instead of thinking about what to do in your current financial situation.

Comment: Finally, I don't understand what you mean by "*what $t$ to choose"*. For what purpose? You can compare "*old and new*" $y_t^*$ for any $t$.

Comment: What is $y^*$ and what is $\hat{y}^*$ ?

Comment: Also, shouldn’t there be a 1 in the denominator of the steady state fraction?

Comment: @Giskard  Solow model has no utility. And there is already a well defined optimum consumption for this model. “Better” in the context of this type of model is generally limited to asking which parameter changes generate a higher level effect or, trivially, a higher rate effect.

Comment: @erik I am not sure I understand - do you have an interpretation of what OP means when they ask which $\hat{y}^*$ steady state level is better? Will you please share it?

Comment: I think the OP means to say “higher” when they write “better”.